# About an ambiguous line in 「東京日和」, a song by Komatsu Miho

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

[The line sings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJgztDpKG4w&feature=youtu.be&t=1m38s):

> わざと訛って
>
> あなたが喋るから
>
> ヘンで笑えた
>
> 上達してないね 今も

I am not sure about the (implied) subject of 「上達してない」.

If 'you' were DELIBERATELY speaking with an accent, I guess 「上達してない」 must not be referring to 'your' pronunciation. Then what can it be referring to? The ability to refrain from laughing out when someone deliberately speaks with an accent?

Any romantic suggestions? :)

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be an explanation related to the song's story. From a piece I found online:

> The Tokyo accent is considered standard Japanese and so speaking
>   another accent is referred to as "namaru ('having an accent')"...
>
> ...And as Miho is not from Tokyo, it would show in her accent, which
>   may have made her feel like an outsider. So her boyfriend spoke a
>   regional accent to make her feel like she didn't have to change her
>   accent to fit in...and that would have given her the confidence not to
>   be insecure about her strange laugh.

This means that the line 上達してないね 今も refers to the fact Miho still didn't improve her ability to speak without a regional accent.

Comment: That is just one fan's interpretation, is it not?  You are using it as if it were THE authoritative source of information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I still have a doubt about the overall explanation. The connection between "speaking with an accent" and "laughing strangely" seems kind of far-fetched. And, "be able to laugh strangely" should be 「ヘンに笑える」 rather than 「へんで笑える」, I guess?

Comment: Yeah, 変で笑えた seems more like "(it was) strange and (I) was able to laugh."

Comment: I've seen this interpretation in many websites @l'électeur
Every single translation I came across supported this too